# Granting Different Rewards For 30 People

Tags: combinatorics

If there are 30 people and 5 different rewards, how many possibilities are there if

1. There are no limitations to the number of rewards per one
2. Only one prize a person

as for 2) we need to choose 5 out of 30 and multiply it by the number of possibilities to order $5$ people in a raw (as the rewards are different) so it is ${30 \choose 5}\cdot5!$

as for 1) how can I do it if there is an option that one will get all the $5$ rewards, that is $4$ possibilities etc. ?

Comment: For 2) why do you need to multiply by 5!? If it's persons, e.g #5, 18, 29, 1, 6, what does it matter in what order the prizes are awarded, it's still the same sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each award has $30$ different choices. Hence, $30^5$.

Comment: and I tried all the time to use $30\choose 5$